# Не срабатывает проверка на типы данных

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть объект с таким типом данных

```
export type JobType = {
    [index: string]: number | string | boolean;
    repeat: number;
    isWork: boolean;
    inQueue: boolean;
    jobName: string; 
    inQueueTime: number;
    isRunningTime: number;
}
```

Есть вот такой вот код:

```
//jobSettings - объект с типом данных JobType
let value: string | number = '';
if (typeof jobSettings[name] === 'number' || typeof jobSettings[name] === 'string') {
    value = jobSettings[name];
}
```

Выдает ошибку внутри `if` на переменной `value`: **TS2322: Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'Key'.   Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Key'.**

Почему, если я проверю тип на `string` и `number`, он это игнорирует и сравнивает с типами данных `JobType`? 
Как это исправить?

Далее эта переменная будет подставлена в атрибут `value` тега `<input>`

Comment: Присвойте временной переменной или обновите TS до 4.7
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#control-flow-analysis-for-bracketed-element-access

Comment: @AlexeyTen я копировал код из вопроса в онлайн-компилятор, в котором 4.8.4, но ошибка там всё равно есть

Comment: Ну тогда первый вариант

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBSEBGAVZqC8cA3gFBzlwDaAlgHYAmoAXHAM4xR0DmAui7QFcAtpmBQ4AHzYdukuJggQANsACGtANxkKUYClUx+w0VC0U41VgHVoAaxYLlazdvJ0AigOBeHilerMKACssADlVIWAWdk5aLg04VwtaT29gbGpIoxExQLdWACUBWlpuDKy4QRzTEgBfEhIAekaQzABlYBgYblY4AFo4QD4QQEYQQCkQQFYQQC4QQCEQOEBBEDhpwA4QQH4QQcAeEDhAFhBABhBAXhA9wGkQQFEQdCxcFBJGAGMlVV04FXhWjq6elgwcPC0bu4enyoRKLSWLxBoAgBuqiUPhBsikVRMcEIAHIUVoSNcILR2HAIci4C9Ot04qxKLQgTwMdQAGZwAAUSBQEDp+Pw7LgKMRYhRkikTOALLxyI5KJi3BRAEpiEkoTCCHitPUgA

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, так работает! Спасибо!

Comment: В целом TS прав, JS насколько гибкий язык, что можно придумать такой код, что в результате в value будет boolean. Но это конечно надо специально изгаляться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS не умеет (пока?) сужать типы свойств объектов. Поэтому нужно сначала переложить его в переменную.

```typescript
export type JobType = {
    [index: string]: number | string | boolean;
    repeat: number;
    isWork: boolean;
    inQueue: boolean;
    jobName: string; 
    inQueueTime: number;
    isRunningTime: number;
}

//jobSettings - объект с типом данных JobType
declare let jobSettings: JobType;
declare let name: string;

let value: string | number = '';

const v = jobSettings[name];

if (typeof v === 'number' || typeof v === 'string') {
    // Тут TS знает что `v` число или строка и присваивание не вызывает ошибки.
    value = v;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBSEBGAVZqC8cA3gFBzlwDaAlgHYAmoAXHAM4xR0DmAui7QFcAtpmBQ4AHzYdukuJggQANsACGtANxkKUYClUx+w0VC0U41VgHVoAaxYLlazdvJ0AigOBeHilerMKACssADlVIWAWdk5aLg04VwtaT29gbGpIoxExQLdWACUBWlpuDKy4QRzTEgBfEhIAekaQzABlYBgYblY4AFo4QD4QQEYQQCkQQFYQQC4QQCEQOEBBEDhpwA4QQH4QQcAeEDhAFhBABhBAXhA9wGkQQFEQdCxcFBJGAGMlVV04FXhWjq6elgwcPC0bu4enyoRKLSWLxBoAgBuqiUPhBsikVRMcEIAHIUVoSNcILR2HAIci4C9Ot04qxKLQgTwtM1zAA9AD8DWoADM4AAKJAoCCs-H4PlwFGIsQoyRSTnAbl45H8lExbgogCUxCSUJhBDxeTgNPMcAZdRIQA)